# PHP "if" , "or" variable equals to

Tags: php

Looking for a bit of PHP help here please..

I am looking to check to see if the contents of a few variables match defined criteria, and if so, to set the value of an additional variable accordingly.

So, I was thinking the below should work... but it has syntax errors which confuse me!

```
if ($var1 == "chicken" || $var == "banana") { $outputVar = "fail" } else { $outputVar = "success" }
```

What is wrong with the above?

Thanks

Comment: at least you are missing a quote

Comment: Missing quote before `banana`?

Comment: Think the missing " is just a typo in here...

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error I get when testing on phpcodechecker.com is "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in your code on line 1"

Comment: Semi colon after var names sorts it

Comment: `if (...) { $outputVar = "fail"; } else { $outputVar = "success"; }`

Comment: [*This is your friend during testing/debugging...*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [*another good read...*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't put `semicolons` in any of your statements. It will solve your problem.

```
if ($var1 == "chicken" || $var == "banana") { $outputVar = "fail"; } else { $outputVar = "success"; }
```

Comment: thanks yep - didnt realise they were needed after declaring the outputvar

Answer (score 0):

You are evalutaing  ($var and $var1 ) this is true? ... and you don't have semicolon at the end

```
if ($var1 == "chicken" || $var == "banana") {
    $outputVar = "fail" ;
 } else {
   $outputVar = "success" ; 
}
```